# Library for zoom pan and get coordinates of a canvas in React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, coordinates, zoom-sdk

I've got a Uint8ClampedArray that comes from my backend representing the pixels array of an image and I'm trying to display it in React + Typescript by using a canvas element.

That's the code:

```
const imgData = new ImageData(
     dataArray, //Uint8ClampedArray
     width,
     height
);

return <Canvas 
     imgData={imgData} 
     canvasHeight={ref.current.offsetHeight} //max height available in the screen
     canvasWidth={ref.current.offsetHeight * ratio}
     imgHeight={height}
     imgWidth={width}
/>

---

export function Canvas(props: Props) {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvasRefCurrent: HTMLCanvasElement = canvasRef.current!;
        const ctx = canvasRefCurrent.getContext("2d", { alpha: false })!;
        ctx.putImageData(props.data, 0, 0);
    }, [props.data]);

    return ( <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        width={props.imgWidth}
        height={props.imgHeight}       
    /> );
```

However, now I'd like to apply zoom/pan to the canvas and to retrieve the coordinates of a clicked point in the image. Does anybody know about any library that can do these actions?

Comment: I don't know of a library to recommend. However, the canvas context has methods for manipulating the transform like [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) and [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate). You can apply these transforms before copying the image data and it should adjust it accordingly. As for converting a mouse coordinate to a pixel coordinate, there's some basic math involved that I'm sure someone has made a blog post for.

Comment: Also side note, `canvasRef.current` *could* be null sometimes. You can add a null check to the beginning of your effect and add `canvasRef` in the dependency array.

Comment: Thank you @Jessie, I added a null check as you suggested and I tried adding the scale function before the putImageData, however it has no effect. I suppose that's because the ImageData is about an 2048 x 1536 image

Comment: I didn't have too much time to look into it but it seems that `putImageData()` directly copies the pixels onto the canvas, meaning it ignores any transforms. [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) is probably what you would want. You can pass it an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) created with [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap). Essentially, you create a bitmap using the raw image data, and then you can draw that bitmap onto the canvas.